# Changing facebook tab icon using php sdk

Tags: facebook-page

I have created a facebook application for addding page tab in any facebook page.

Everything is working fine but i am not able to change the icon the tab i am adding.

I am using following code of php sdk

```
if($facebook->api($tabid, 'POST', array(
'custom_name' => $tabtitle,
'image_url'=>$newname,
'is_non_connection_landing_tab'=>1,
'access_token'=>$mpagetoken
))
```

Please tell me where i am wrong in this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such field as `image_url` in [`page` tabs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs).

Actually tab icon is the application icon which is [`icon_url` field of `application` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#fields), and while some of fields may be edited by issuing `POST` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID?PROPERTY_1=PROPERTY_VALUE` this field isn't marked as editable:

> Not all app properties can be edited via the API, please refer to the properties in the [table above](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#fields) for an indication of whether a property can be edited or not.